# Why does sorting a list of dict keys in one line, with .sort() not work, while sorted() does?

Tags: python, list, sorting

While practicing Python (3.7.3), I find myself wanting to sort the keys of a dict. But I am walking up against something I don't understand, and can't find explained on SO.

**edit:** I know that the sort() method changes the list itself, while sorted() leaves the original list intact and returns new one. But can someone explain why the list() constructor doesn't seem to return the list anymore when I call it's sort() method?

Can someone explain why this doesn't return anything:

```
>>> md = {5: 3, 2: 1, 8: 9}
>>> ml = list(md.keys()).sort()
>>> ml
>>>
```

While if I do it in two separate steps, it does work:

```
>>> ml = list(md.keys())
>>> ml
[5, 2, 8]
>>> ml.sort()
>>> ml
[2, 5, 8]
>>>
```

Also, I found that doing it in one line using `sorted()`, it works as well:

```
>>> sorted(list(md.keys()))
[2, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 3):

`sort` sorts the iterable *in-place*, but returns `None`, which is assigned to `ml`. That's why the REPL does not show anything.

On the contrary, `sorted` returns a sorted representation of the original iterable.

Comment: That helps, but I am still using the list constructor, which should return a list. So, can you explain why the list() constructor doesn't return a list in this case?

Comment: The call to `list` returns a list, biut you're calling `sort` on that list after the construction of the list (obviously) and assign its return value which is `None`.

Comment: @RikSchoonbeek: the list constructor does create an object of type list. on that object, you call the `sort` method. The `sort` method sorts that, but the result of calling the function evaluates to None (it's a "void" function). The sorted object is not assigned to anything and is lost.

Answer (score 1):

`sort()` sorts directly your array, while `sorted()` returns a **new** array. ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html))

Comment: That helps, but I am still using the list constructor, which should return a list. So, can you explain why the list() constructor doesn't return a list in this case?